# Providing initial data django unit test

Tags: python, sql, django, unit-testing

I'm working on a Django application which have a lot of unit tests. 
Some of those test functionalities on unmanaged models (Manage = False). In order to test them, there are in **setUpClass** the execution of some sql files.

Now, after upgrading at Django 1.11.2, some warnings are raised during the execution of sql files. 
The warning is the following:

```
Warning: Unknown table '<table name>' return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
```

I searched the reason of this warning and seems it is linked to the sql file that check if the table exists before create or drop it.

I would remove this warnings, and to do this, I thought of drop the table in **tearDownClass**, in order to remove the `IF EXISTS` statements in sql files. 
I think that this approach makes unit tests slower and I don't know if it is a best practice.

Furthermore, I found in Django documentation that is possible use [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/initial-data/) to providing initial data. Since documentation is not very clear (from my point of view) on how use fixtures in unit tests, I'm asking this question to understand how is the best practice/approach to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I did not understand your concern fully. However if the problem is loading initial data (fixtures) for testing, that can be done with following procedures:

```
class Test1(TestCase):
    fixtures = [
       "fixtures.json",
    ]

    def setUp(self):
        ...

    // test cases
```

More information on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading

##### Update

Django 5.0 docs (Feb 2024)

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading